# Why isn't my custom Spring aspect triggered?

Tags: java, spring, scala, aop, aspectj

I want to weave the following custom aspect using Spring 4.X.
(I use Scala, but is exactly the same as in Java).
I'm based on this existing [code](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_identityaccess/src/main/java/com/saasovation/identityaccess/application/IdentityAccessEventProcessor.java), acting as sample from the Vaughn Vernon's IDDD book:

```
@Aspect
@Component
class EventProcessor @Autowired()(private val eventRepository: EventRepository) {

  @Before("execution(* com.mymainpackage.*.application.commands.*.*(..)")
  def listen() {
    DomainEventPublisher.instance().subscribe(new DomainEventSubscriber[Event] {

      def handleEvent(domainEvent: Event) {
        eventRepository.save(domainEvent)
      }

      def subscribedToEventType = {
        classOf[Event]
      }
    })
  }

}
```

My `application-context.xml`:

```
.........
<context:load-time-weaver/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan
        base-package="........" />
```

The typical classes/services I want to weave with aspect contains this kind of method:

```
def handle(event:Event)
```

and its corresponding interfaces and implementation may be found in this explicit package for instance:

```
com.mymainpackage.myboundedcontext1.application.commands.anestedpackage
```

I well checked that the base-package contains the class's package of the custom aspect.

Is there a necessity to declare a `@PointCut` additionally to `@Before`?
The sample doesn't do it...
Of course, I executed my code with the following jar allowing "weaving" at Runtime so:

```
-javaagent:/cache/org.springframework/spring-instrument/jars/spring-instrument-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Did I miss something "obvious"?
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: For starters your pointcut is missing a closing `)`. For loadtime weaving to work you also need a `aop.xml` make sure that you have that also. Only aspects declared in there will be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @M.Deinum mentionned, I forgot a last `)` regarding the matcher of my pointcut.

Furthermore I forgot to specify the aspectj-autoproxy, in order to take into account my aspect class.
With that, would no need to declare an aop.xml if I expect all aspects classes to have their created respective proxies.

So I specified it by adding spring-aop xsd to my `application-context.xml` like this ("------->" to make a legend, although not valid :) in this xml):

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"       ------->That is added
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.1.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd" ---------> That is added >

      .....
      <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
      .....
```

Now the whole works.